# How to regexp split to table regexed splitted table

Tags: postgresql

I have table with combined string and I want to split it to first parts. I have results from query with regexped split to table.

Now i have split from this: `1:9,5:4,4:8,6:9,3:9,2:5,7:8,34:8,24:6`
to this table:

```
campaign_skill
----------------
1:9
5:4
4:8
6:9
3:9
2:5
7:8
34:8
24:6
```

with this expression:

```
select * 
from regexp_split_to_table((select user_skill from users where user_token = 'ded8ab43-efe2-4aea-894d-511ed3505261'), E'[\\s,]+') as campaign_skill
```

How to split actual results to tables like this:

```
campaign | skill
---------|------
1        | 9
5        | 4
4        | 8
6        | 9
3        | 9
2        | 5
7        | 8
34       | 8
24       | 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split_part()` for that.

```
select split_part(t.campaign_skill, ':', 1) as campaign,
       split_part(t.campaign_skill, ':', 2) as skill
from users u, 
     regexp_split_to_table(u.user_skill, E'[\\s,]+') as t(campaign_skill)
where u.user_token = 'ded8ab43-efe2-4aea-894d-511ed3505261';
```